# Measuring Non idealities in an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

First time poster:

I want to learn about opamps. I am just a college graduate with no practical experience.

What I know:

A few basic high level applications such as

Hysteresis,
Voltage follower,
Inverting and non inverting configuration,
Various Filters, and
Oscialltors

All these we studied (and some lab experiments) and passed but I want to learn deeper.

1. I want to use the worst(where I can feel the effects such as offset voltage, offset current, leakage current, etc) opamp available (I couldn't find the question here but I remember, it is useful)
2. And do practical measurements with oscilloscope and understand and see it practically.

I will put all the efforts needed. I want a direction to start with.

How can I start?

Please suggest if i have to share any other details.

Comment: i think, it it is difficult to say, what is the worst op amp. Every OpAm aviable to be bought, should work for some purpose, otherwise, it would not be sold.

Comment: @SirSy forgive my ignorance. I meant any opamp where I can measure the parameters with normal oscilloscope in the lab.

Comment: How did you graduate with no practical experience?

Comment: @LeonHeller only practical experience i got is with lab experiments

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't do what you want. For measuring DC levels like mV and uA, a scope is not the way to go. Get a decent multimeter. With that said, if you want bad you can't do better (worse?) than the classic 741. If you feel you can't afford a meter, resign yourself to working with high resistor values while at the same time understanding how to take measurements without the scope input impedance corrupting your data.

Comment: Hi, @Sonder I would love to point you to a document which describes an experimental procedure using a cheap multimeter (No high-end stuff required) to measure the non-idealities of an op-amp. Kindly accept some edits to the question which I believe make it useful to others.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I have access to good multimeters and oscilloscopes in my lab. I will start with 741 IC. Can you answer with any more helpful details?

Comment: @ijuneja I would love to. I don't see any options to accept the edit. I will check again.

Comment: Read all the Application Notes from TI and AD

Comment: Start by going to the data sheets for old op amps such as the 741, 709, etc. In many of these, the circuits for measuring things like offsets are presented, along with component values. Modern op amps are typically so good that very often simple circuits don't work. For instance, reliably measuring fA currents or nV voltages is not for the faint of heart, newcomers, or those without deep pockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of (or in addition to) on-the-bench experiments you should also consider using a **circuit simulator** to experiment.

You can then make your own opamp model, start with a voltage controlled voltage source with a gain of 1000 and see what happens. It is then easy to add input offset, play with the gain, include a bandwidth limitation etc.
In a simulator you have full control so you're not limited to DC offsets of a few mV, you can set it to 1 V DC if you like.

LTSpice is an example of a suitable simulator.

Also have you read "[Opamps for everyone](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf)" ?

Comment: I had seen it, yes but I was not sure whether it is for me. It is a big commitment of 465 pages. May I know your suggestion about starting with the book?

Comment: I have LTSpice. We use it. Can you help me a lil more to a guide or book for creating my own opamp.

Comment: I second the nomination for "Op Amps for Everyone". I have the free pdf version that TI gave away...see chapter 11 for consideration of non-ideal op amp behavior.

Comment: I have upvoted both answers but it is not visible to others because of reputation. Important thing is the point to start with. I will start with opamps for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Linked Below is a folder containing a document named Non-idealities in Opamp.pdf. The doc was created by [Prof. M.B Patil](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/wiki/faculty/mbpatil), Department of Electrical Engineering, IIT Bombay for the course EE 230 : Analog Lab at IITB

The said document describes some simple experiments to measure the Input Offset Voltage and the Input bias current of an op-amp.

The document also describes a method to determine the open loop gain of an op-amp.

It is recommended to perform the experiment with the BJT based op-amp 741 since this op-amp will have parameters well within the measurable range.

The folder also contains a lab report which was prepared by me after performing this experiment in the assigned lab. It may prove useful.

[Folder Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oB3VyeDEbgyZqDUYB1C02AkidFqN7vWs)

Comment: @Sonder sure! Just a quick suggestion, don't forget to upvote the answer if you find it useful and accept it (The green check mark) if it solves what you were looking for